# Create hidden, non visible window in X?

Tags: c, linux, unix, x11

Is it possible in X to create a window that is not visible? I looked at the XCreateSimpleWindow API but did not find any attributes to make it hidden. Is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: You want a window that has no effect on the screen but still gets events?

Comment: @Vaughn, That's got to be it. Otherwise use XCreateSimpleWindow() and don't XMapWindow(). But it's like a tachyon; no way to tell if it's *really there* or not. Hence, useless. ... Unless you need a dummy target to test the performance of window calls, without actually needing any output... maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for an InputOnly window.  You can specify the class as InputOnly when using XCreateWindow.