# How to create an invisible X11 window for GPGPU?

Tags: x11, opengl-es-2.0, gpgpu, egl

Is it possible to create an invisible X window? For initialization of an OpenGL ES 2.0 context, one has to create a X window manually, but I can't find a way to make it invisible. Since I'm only doing GPGPU I don't need an output window. In fact, it is rather annoying in my case.

I'm aware of a solution from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856768/create-hidden-non-visible-window-in-x), where it has been pointed out to use `InputOnly` in `XCreateWindow()`. This, however, leads to the X error `GLXBadDrawable`. Probably because EGL requires the window to respond to graphics request. Is there another way? Maybe create it minimized? But I can't find anything on that either. Also setting the window's size really small doesn't help, since it always occupies the whole screen on my device (Nokia N9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an X window, it is created unmapped, so what about creating an InputOutput window and leaving it unmapped? Another option would be (if the window must stay mapped), to move it out of the screen.

Comment: Great! Removing the call to `XMapWindow()` during window creation perfectly did the trick. Thanks!